# Does Android not supports Java?

Tags: java

Redmi 6 does not support java. 
Redmi Note 5 support java through third party support.

What's the difference?

I read on Quora that by not supporting Java I can't go to Play Store.

Answer (score 4):

## Java

Java is used for developing Android apps, however Android devices itself never supports executing Java (code) out of the box.

## Google Play Store

All devices which are certified by Google have access to the Google Play Store.
The complete list of certified devices is available at Google:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en

In this list you can find for example:

> Xiaomi Redmi 6 cereus Redmi 6
>
> Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 whyred Redmi Note 5
>
> Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 Pro whyred Redmi Note 5
>
> Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 Pro whyred Redmi Note 5 Pro
>
> Xiaomi Redmi Note 5A ugg Redmi Note 5A
>
> Xiaomi Redmi Note 5A ugg Redmi Y1
>
> Xiaomi Redmi Note 5A ugglite Redmi Note 5A